# trouble with my nested for loops achieve results similar to a sumif

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to cycle through 2 lists using for loops to calculate the sum for each unique reference. I suppose I'm looking for a pythonic sumif!

```
# list of data ("user_ID", "contract_Number", "weight", "type")
list1 = [
    ('1','261','6.2','Input'),
    ('1','262','7.2','Input'),
    ('1','263','5.2','Input'),
    ('1','264','8.2','Input'),
    ('1','261','3.2','Input'),
    ('1','262','2.2','Input'),
    ('1','262','7.2','Input'),
    ('1','263','4.2','Input'),
    ('1','264','6.2','Input'),
    ('1','265','6.2','Input'),
    ('1','261','9.2','Input'),
    ('1','261','10.2','Input')
    ]

contract_list = []

# create a list of contract numbers
for data_row in list1:
    if data_row[0] == "1" and data_row[3] == "Input":
        contract_list.append(data_row[1])

#remove duplication - left with a list of unique contract numbers
contract_list = list(dict.fromkeys(contract_list))
print(contract_list)


# I'm trying this...[28.6, 16.6, 9.4, 14.4, 6.2]
tally_list = []
tally = 0
for c in contract_list:
    for l in list1:
        if data_row[0] == '1' and data_row[1] == contract_list[0]:
            tally = tally + float(data_row[2])
    tally_list.append(tally)

print(tally_list)
```

I'm expecting...
['261', '262', '263', '264', '265']
[28.6, 16.6, 9.4, 14.4, 6.2]

I'm getting...
['261', '262', '263', '264', '265']
[122.40000000000002, 244.7999999999999, 367.19999999999976, 489.5999999999996, 612.0]

Comment: `tally` is initialized to zero and thereafter the loop keeps adding to it, so of course it just grows and grows.  Perhaps you meant to reset it back to zero at some point inside the loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
# I'm trying this...[28.6, 16.6, 9.4, 14.4, 6.2]
tally_list = []
tally = 0
for c in contract_list:
    for l in list1:   #<----------
        if data_row[0] == '1' and data_row[1] == contract_list[0]:
            tally = tally + float(data_row[2])
    tally_list.append(tally)
```

In the marked row, it looks like you want to use the `data_row` variable instead of `l`

---

Actually, try this, you need to additionally reset `tally` and also use `c` instead of `contract_list[0]` in the final `if` statement.

```
# I'm trying this...[28.6, 16.6, 9.4, 14.4, 6.2]
tally_list = []
tally = 0
for c in contract_list:
    for data_row in list1:        
        if data_row[0] == '1' and data_row[1] == c: #<----
            tally = tally + float(data_row[2])
    tally_list.append(tally)
    tally=0 #<---



print(tally_list)
```

Comment: That creates a list that looks like this [28.8, 28.8, 28.8, 28.8, 28.8]. I think I need to reset the variable with each loop?

Comment: Yes, should reset the variable. I updated the answer, including one more fix.

Answer (score 0):

Just another approach using a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
from collections import defaultdict

list1 = [
    ('1','261','6.2','Input'),
    ('1','262','7.2','Input'),
    ('1','263','5.2','Input'),
    ('1','264','8.2','Input'),
    ('1','261','3.2','Input'),
    ('1','262','2.2','Input'),
    ('1','262','7.2','Input'),
    ('1','263','4.2','Input'),
    ('1','264','6.2','Input'),
    ('1','265','6.2','Input'),
    ('1','261','9.2','Input'),
    ('1','261','10.2','Input')
    ]

d = defaultdict(int)

for tup in list1:
    if tup[0] == '1' and tup[3] == 'Input':
        d[tup[1]] += float(tup[2])

contract_list = list(d)
print(contract_list)

tally_list = [format(v, '.1f') for v in d.values()]
print(tally_list)
```

Output:

```
['261', '262', '263', '264', '265']
['28.8', '16.6', '9.4', '14.4', '6.2']
```